# Powershell script to automate create Ad User and group member

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Iam begineer to powershell, trying to create a AD User and a group member, here the query is groups should be **array** (multiple groups)it shouldn't be one to one mapping using for loop, try and catch method need to check all the scenarioes like user already exists on AD as well as Group if not exists add **New-ADUser** and group **Add-ADGroupMember**
the code which i was trying but somewhere the logic missed or my script is not correct, its not going inside  **foreach ($grp in $Group)**

```
Param
(
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $fname,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $lname,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $upn,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $desc,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $Email,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string[]] $Group
)
# Define UPN

$SamAccount = "$fname.$lname"
$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$SamAccount'" | Select-Object SamAccountName
#$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Select-Object Name

#Generate a Randam Secure Password to a User
Function GenerateStrongPassword ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$PasswordLenght)
{
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$PassComplexCheck = $false
do {
$newPassword=[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword($PasswordLenght,1)
If ( ($newPassword -cmatch "[A-Z\p{Lu}\s]") `
-and ($newPassword -cmatch "[a-z\p{Ll}\s]") `
-and ($newPassword -match "[\d]") `
-and ($newPassword -match "[^\w]")
)
{
$PassComplexCheck=$True
}
} While ($PassComplexCheck -eq $false)
return $newPassword
}
$password = GenerateStrongPassword (10)


#Adding New User to AD and to the Groups

if ($ADUser -eq $null){
New-ADUser -GivenName "$fname" -Surname "$lname" -Initials $initials -displayName "${fname} ${lname}" -UserPrincipalName $upn -Description "$desc" -Name "$fname $lname" -EmailAddress "$email" -SamAccountName $SamAccount -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -AccountPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $false -Path "OU=aws,DC=azure,DC=com" -Server "Domain"
"ResponseMessage: successfull- User " +$UPN+ "  added to the AD and user's password is " +$password 
foreach ($grp in $Group)
   {
     $grp = $grp.tostring()
     $ADGroups = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp| Select-Object name
    if($ADGroups -eq $null){
     Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Members $ADUser
    "ResponseMessage: successfull- User " +$UPN+ " added to the $grp"
    }
}
}
#if Ad user already exists but not exist on Group
elseif($ADUser){
    "ResponseMessage: successfull- User " +$UPN+ " is already exists to the AD"
    foreach ($grp in $Group)
   {
     $grp = $grp.tostring()
     $ADGroups = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp| Select-Object name
     if($ADGroups -eq $null){
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Members $ADUser
    "ResponseMessage: successfull- User " +$UPN+ " added to the $grp"
    }
    else{
        "User is " +$UPN+ " is already exists on the $grp"
    }
    }
}
else{
    "user is not valid"
}
```

Comment: can you update that into your post on what your question is? In your code, you never define `$Group`.

Comment: **[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string[]] $Group**  its defined on parameters

Comment: I see it now, thank you. Inside your `if` statement, you never reference the newly created user. You have a `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Members $ADUser` that is referencing a null `$ADUser` seeing as thats the reason it got placed inside that conditional statement to begin with. You should be able to use `$ADUser = New-ADUser ... -PassThru`

Comment: in my code **$ADUser** is a variable to get the users list on AD, do i need to modify to **$ADUser = New-ADUser ... -PassThru**

Comment: Your `if` statement is **only** ran when `$ADUser` is *null*.  This means that `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Members $ADUser` is attempting to add a `$ADUser` (that is *null*) to the `$grp`. You just have to assign the creation of the new user to `$ADUser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main issues is you're attempting to add `$ADUser` to `$grp` while it's *null*. You have `if ($ADUser -eq $null){..}` which will only run if `$ADUser` is null, then you're attempting to use `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Members $ADUser` where it will not work. Your immediate fix is to assign the newly created user account to `$ADUser`; `$ADUser = New-ADUser`.

The next issue would be the way you're comparing to see if the user is already part of the group via `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp` which will not tell you that, besides getting the group members of the specified group. You can fix this by querying for the `memberof` property and comparing your `$grp` to the returned user groups; `$grp` also doesn't need to be converted to a string (*`.ToString()`*) seeing as it's already a string via your `[string[]] $Groups` explicit cast type.

Fixing the above, you end up with this:

```
Param
(
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $fname,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $lname,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $upn,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $desc,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $Email,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string[]] $Group
)
# Define UPN

$SamAccount = "$fname.$lname"
$ADUser = try { Get-ADUser -Identity $SamAccount -Properties 'memberof' } catch { }

#Adding New User to AD and to the Groups
if ($null -eq $ADUser) {
    $newUserParams = @{
        GivenName = $fname
        Surname   = $lname
        Initials  = $initials
        DisplayName = "$fname $lname"
        UserPrincipalName = $upn
        Description  = $desc
        Name         = "$fname $lname"
        EmailAddress = $Email
        SamAccountName = $SamAccount
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
        AccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
        Enabled  = $false 
        Path     = "OU=aws,DC=azure,DC=com" 
        Server   = "Domain"
        PassThru = $true
    }
    $ADUser = New-ADUser @newUserParams
    "ResponseMessage: successfull- User $UPN added to the AD and user's password is $password"
    foreach ($grp in $Group)
    {
        $ADGroups = try { Get-ADGroup -Identity $grp } catch { }
        if ($ADGroups) {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Members $ADUser.SAMAccountName
            "ResponseMessage: successfull- User " + $UPN + " added to the $grp"
        }
    }
}
elseif ($ADUser) {
    "ResponseMessage: successfull- User " + $UPN + " is already exists to the AD"
    $userGroups = $ADUser.MemberOf.Foreach{ ($_ -Split 'CN=|,OU')[1] }
    foreach ($grp in $Group)
    {
        if ($grp -notin $userGroups) {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Members $ADUser.SAMAccountName
            "ResponseMessage: successfull- User $UPN added to the $grp"
        }
        else {
            "User $UPN already exists in $grp"
        }
    }
}
else {
    "user is not valid"
}
```

---

*I removed the function `GenerateStrongPassword` for brevity; just re-add it.*